# RSwag `consumes` method does work in RSpec context

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, http-headers, content-type, rswag

I am trying to test for wrong content type with RSwag and I put `consumes` method in a shared context

```rb
path '/api/profile' do
  get 'profile' do
    consumes 'application/json'
    produces 'application/json'
    
    it_behaves_like 'handles errors'

    response(200, 'it works') do
      run_test!
    end
  end
end

shared_examples 'handles errors' do
  context 'no credentials' do
    response(401, 'unauthorized') do
      run_test!
    end
  end

  context 'wrong data type' do
    consumes 'text/html'
    response(415, 'unsupported media type') do
      run_test!
    end
  end
end
```

This is not working because `consumes` seems to override `Content-Type` for other test cases as well. I can pass 'Content-Type' header manually, but it seems redundant. Is this by design? Is there any convenient workaround?

Comment: `let('Content-Type'){ 'text/html' }` works, and it's pretty neat, but I wonder if this can be reflected in swagger, and `consumes` method goes out of the boundaries of the context